# Camera Pose Estimation Accuracy with ArUco Board

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I am using ArUco Board to get camera position and attitude. In this case, the marker (ArUco Board) is my reference (origin).
[image]
But when I rotate camera(drone) around its own axis (around yaw angle), after -10 degree yaw angle, position estimation error is becoming very large (especially y-axis).

Yaw Degree: 19
[image]

Yaw Degree: 0
[image]

Yaw Degree: -10
[image]

.
.

I also collected whole x and y axes position estimation datas and printed on graphs. When you review the graph, after -10 degree yaw angle, y-axis position estimation error is becoming very large.

Why? How can I increase accuracy? How can I prevent this situation?
[image]

I also used all refinement methods.

```
aruco.CORNER_REFINE_NONE
aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX
aruco.CORNER_REFINE_CONTOUR
aruco.CORNER_REFINE_APRILTAG
```

The result is same.

Code:

```
from djitellopy import tello
import time
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import aruco
import sys, math

telloDroneEnabled = 1   # Aruco Board detection Laptop Camera or Tello Drone Camera
                        # telloDroneEnabled = 1 : Aruco Detection with Tello Drone Camera
                        # telloDroneEnabled = 0 : Aruco Detection with Laptop Camera

w, h = 640, 480

#---------------- ARUCO MARKER ---------------#
# Create vectors we'll be using for rotations and translations for postures
rvec, tvec = None, None
R_ct = 0
R_tc = 0

corners = 0

#--- Get the camera calibration path
calib_path  = ""
if telloDroneEnabled == 0:
    cameraMatrix   = np.loadtxt(calib_path+'cameraMatrix_asusWebcam.txt', delimiter=',')
    distCoeffs = np.loadtxt(calib_path+'cameraDistortion_asusWebcam.txt', delimiter=',')
elif telloDroneEnabled == 1:
    cameraMatrix = np.loadtxt(calib_path + 'cameraMatrix_telloCamera.txt', delimiter=',')
    distCoeffs = np.loadtxt(calib_path + 'cameraDistortion_telloCamera.txt', delimiter=',')

#--- 180 deg rotation matrix around the x axis
R_flip  = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.float32)
R_flip[0,0] = 1.0
R_flip[1,1] =-1.0
R_flip[2,2] =-1.0

#--- Define the aruco dictionary
# Constant parameters used in Aruco methods
ARUCO_PARAMETERS = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
ARUCO_DICT = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_5X5_1000)

# Create grid board object we're using in our stream
board = aruco.GridBoard_create(
            markersX=4,
            markersY=6,
            markerLength=0.06,
            markerSeparation=0.01,
            dictionary=ARUCO_DICT)

landingPadPosXY = [0.0] * 2
landingPadDetected = 0
landingPadLostCNTR = 0
landingPadDistanceXY = 0.0
newPadPositionReady = 0
rangefinder = 0
thresholdQR = 5

battery = 0

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------- ROTATIONS https://www.learnopencv.com/rotation-matrix-to-euler-angles/
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Checks if a matrix is a valid rotation matrix.
def isRotationMatrix(R):
    Rt = np.transpose(R)
    shouldBeIdentity = np.dot(Rt, R)
    I = np.identity(3, dtype=R.dtype)
    n = np.linalg.norm(I - shouldBeIdentity)
    return n < 1e-2


# Calculates rotation matrix to euler angles
# The result is the same as MATLAB except the order
# of the euler angles ( x and z are swapped ).
def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R):
    assert (isRotationMatrix(R))

    sy = math.sqrt(R[0, 0] * R[0, 0] + R[1, 0] * R[1, 0])

    singular = sy < 1e-2

    if not singular:
        x = math.atan2(R[2, 1], R[2, 2])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = math.atan2(R[1, 0], R[0, 0])
    else:
        x = math.atan2(-R[1, 2], R[1, 1])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = 0

    return np.array([x, y, z])

if telloDroneEnabled == 0:
    #--- Capture the videocamera (this may also be a video or a picture)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # -- Set the camera size as the one it was calibrated with
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, h)
    # cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 40)
elif telloDroneEnabled == 1:
    me = tello.Tello()
    me.connect()
    print(me.get_battery())
    me.streamon()

#-- Font for the text in the image
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

prev_frame_time = 0

while True:
    # -- Read the camera frame
    if telloDroneEnabled == 0:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    elif telloDroneEnabled == 1:
        frame = me.get_frame_read().frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (w, h))

    # -- Convert in gray scale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # -- remember, OpenCV stores color images in Blue, Green, Red

    # Detect Aruco markers
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, ARUCO_DICT, parameters=ARUCO_PARAMETERS)

    # Refine detected markers
    # Eliminates markers not part of our board, adds missing markers to the board
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints, recoveredIds = aruco.refineDetectedMarkers(
        image=gray,
        board=board,
        detectedCorners=corners,
        detectedIds=ids,
        rejectedCorners=rejectedImgPoints,
        cameraMatrix=cameraMatrix,
        distCoeffs=distCoeffs)

    # Outline all of the markers detected in our image
    frame = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners, ids, borderColor=(0, 255, 0))

    # Require 1 markers before drawing axis
    if ids is not None and len(ids) > 0:
        # Estimate the posture of the gridboard, which is a construction of 3D space based on the 2D video
        pose, rvec, tvec = aruco.estimatePoseBoard(corners, ids, board, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec)

        if pose:
            # Draw the camera posture calculated from the gridboard
            #tvec[2] = tvec[2] * (-1)
            #frame = aruco.drawAxis(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec, 0.3)
            frame = cv2.drawFrameAxes(frame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec, 0.2)

            tvec[0] *= 95
            tvec[1] *= 95
            tvec[2] *= 95

            # -- Print the tag position in camera frame
            # str_position = "MARKER Position x=%4.0f  y=%4.0f  z=%4.0f"%(tvec[0], tvec[1], tvec[2])
            # cv2.putText(frame, str_position, (0, 360), font, 1.3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            # -- Obtain the rotation matrix tag->camera
            R_ct = np.matrix(cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)[0])
            R_tc = R_ct.T

            # -- Get the attitude in terms of euler 321 (Needs to be flipped first)
            roll_marker, pitch_marker, yaw_marker = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R_flip*R_tc)

            #-- Print the marker's attitude respect to camera frame
            # str_attitude = "MARKER Attitude r=%4.0f  p=%4.0f  y=%4.0f"%(math.degrees(roll_marker),math.degrees(pitch_marker),
            #                     math.degrees(yaw_marker))
            # cv2.putText(frame, str_attitude, (0, 380), font, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            # -- Now get Position and attitude f the camera respect to the marker
            pos_camera = -R_tc * np.matrix(tvec)
            str_position = "CAMERA Position x=%4.0f  y=%4.0f"%(pos_camera[2], pos_camera[0])
            cv2.putText(frame, str_position, (0, 430), font, 1.4, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

            # -- Get the attitude of the camera respect to the frame
            pitch_camera, yaw_camera, roll_camera = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R_flip * R_tc)
            str_attitude = "CAMERA Attitude roll=%4.1f  pitch=%4.1f  yaw=%4.1f"%(math.degrees(roll_camera),math.degrees(pitch_camera),
                                math.degrees(yaw_camera))
            cv2.putText(frame, str_attitude, (0, 460), font, 1.4, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)


    # calculate the FPS and display on frame
    new_frame_time = time.time()
    if telloDroneEnabled == 0:
        fps = 1 / (new_frame_time - prev_frame_time)
        prev_frame_time = new_frame_time
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS" + str(int(fps)), (10, 40), font, 1.3, (100, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    elif telloDroneEnabled == 1:
        cv2.putText(frame, "Battery:%" + str(battery), (10, 40), font, 1.3, (100, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    # cv2.putText(frame, "Land OK: " + str(int(landingPadDetected)), (10, 60), font, 1.3, (100, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # --- Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if telloDroneEnabled == 1:
        battery = me.get_battery()

    #         time.sleep(0.5)

    # --- use 'q' to quit
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        if telloDroneEnabled == 0:
            cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you estimate the camera pose?

Comment: If not: Check whether youreally estimate canera pose (with board origin) or maybe board pose (with canera origin)!

Comment: @Micka I added the code. I used rotation matrix to use marker as reference (origin).

Comment: Thx, hard to read all the code on the mobile, I will try to do it on pc later. Are you aware that aruco.estimatePoseBoard estimates the pose of the board, relative to the camera, not the pose of the camera relative to the board?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know that. Because of that, I am using rotation matrix to change reference frame.

Comment: Can you explain that approach? Is it badically inverting the transformation? Did you only invert rotation or also translation?

Comment: Yes, inverting rotation and translation. With this way, I can get camera position in terms of marker origin. So position should be independent from camera yaw angle. Because I am not changing its position, just rotating it around its own axis. Until -10 degree yaw angle, everything works great. But after that angle, estimation is giving very bad results. Can it occur because of bad camera calibration?

Comment: If I understand it right, you dont invert the full pose but only rotation, because you aussume that the translation stays the same for each rotation? That's a wrong assumption, because the function initially estimates the board pose, where the board translation and rotation change when you rotate the camera. Can you try to compose the 4x4 transformation matrix from raw rvec and tvec and invert it as a whole?

Comment: You removed tvec[2] = tvec[2] * (-1) on purpose? You could try to add it after drawing the board axis

Comment: Yes, just tried something with tvec[2] = tvec[2] * (-1). If you reviewed my code fully, still do you think my approach is wrong?

Comment: I guess I wrote something wrong for rotation matrix explanation. Because I used rvec vector and rodrigues method for reference frame transformation as you can see in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. After re-calibration with chessboard, I get better results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).